# Split Connection String

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

In a WinForm Application I Store My ConnectionString in App.Confing File.How Can I split this connectionstring to some Data like username,DataBaseName,Password and other thing Dynamically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

And what you exactly need is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7z89tex.aspx

Answer (score 15):

I don't understand why all MSDN examples show ugly way by using Keys.

We can access primary data through properties:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder decoder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

string UserID = decoder.UserID; 
string Password = decoder.Password;
```

Comment: Note: SqlConnection only works against Microsoft SQL databases, other valid connection strings might not fit their schema.

Answer (score 0):

This topic from msdn library might be help you :-

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)